# LibGDX: BufferedImage into Texture

Tags: opengl, libgdx, bufferedimage, xuggler

I'm trying to play videos within a LibGDX application. I've managed to load the individual video frames sequentially into a `java.awt.BufferedImage` using [Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler).

Now I'm stuck trying to get that into a LibGDX `Texture`. Anyone know a way to do this?

I managed to find these two LibGDX files that happen to *use* `BufferedImage`'s, however can't see how to use this to get my data into a Texture :(

- [LibGDX JoglPixmap.java](http://libgdx.googlecode.com/svn-history/r192/trunk/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/desktop/JoglPixmap.java)
- [LibGDX JoglTexture.java](http://libgdx.googlecode.com/svn-history/r195/trunk/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/desktop/JoglTexture.java)

Comment: Footnote: AFAIK no-one has successfully managed to get video playback from within LibGDX yet. If someone already has, feel free to post that as an answer :)

Comment: [Have a look here](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/30607/play-videos-with-libgdx).

Comment: the JOGL files you list are part of the libGDX backend.  They are how libGDX implements its API on the desktop, when using JOGL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as soon as you transformed your bufferedImage to a pixmap just use the Texture constructor passing in a pixmap:

```
 Texture newTexture = new Texture(myPixmap);
```

There are methods to construct an empty Pixmap and draw onto it. Use this pixmap then as described above

Answer (score 0):

If you are using LibGDX, I have to say that I don't recommend also using BufferedImages (from Java2D), instead you could use a Pixmap, or if you really do need BufferedImages, then I guess you could use ImageIO to save the image to a file, bring the file back in as a texture, then delete the file, but that seems quite hacky and inefficient.